Can I use Vertex Prompt optimiser with Gemini with grounding
I want to try and optimise my prompts when using Gemini with grounding using Vertex prompt optimiser. Is it possible to use both of them together?
It seems to me like the answer is no given that the examples here for vertex prompt optimiser only uses the raw gemini models rather than being able to use grounding.
I.e. The tutorial here doesn't seem to allow for gemini with grounding. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/learn/prompts/prompt-optimizer#notebook_1
Specifically, the following code in this tutorial only allows a gemini model to be included as a string:
params = {
    "project": PROJECT_ID,
    "num_steps": NUM_INST_OPTIMIZATION_STEPS,
    "system_instruction": SYSTEM_INSTRUCTION,
    "prompt_template": PROMPT_TEMPLATE,
    "target_model": TARGET_MODEL,
    "target_model_qps": TARGET_MODEL_QPS,
    "target_model_location": LOCATION,
    "source_model": SOURCE_MODEL,
    "source_model_qps": SOURCE_MODEL_QPS,
    "source_model_location": LOCATION,
    "eval_qps": EVAL_QPS,
    "eval_model_location": LOCATION,
    "optimization_mode": OPTIMIZATION_MODE,
    "num_demo_set_candidates": NUM_DEMO_OPTIMIZATION_STEPS,
    "demo_set_size": NUM_DEMO_PER_PROMPT,
    "aggregation_type": METRIC_AGGREGATION_TYPE,
    "data_limit": 50,
    "num_template_eval_per_step": NUM_TEMPLATES_PER_STEP,
    "input_data_path": input_data_path,
    "output_path": output_path,
    "response_mime_type": RESPONSE_MIME_TYPE,
    "language": TARGET_LANGUAGE,
    "placeholder_to_content": json.loads(PLACEHOLDER_TO_VALUE),
}


Run the Vertex AI prompt optimizer using one of the following options in these case I use Python:
Before trying this sample, follow the Python setup instructions in the Vertex AI quickstart using client libraries. For more information, see the Vertex AI Python API reference documentation.
To authenticate to Vertex AI, set up Application Default Credentials. For more information, see Set up authentication for a local development environment.
from google.cloud import aiplatform

# Initialize Vertex AI platform
aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location="us-central1")

# TODO(Developer): Check and update lines below
# cloud_bucket = "gs://cloud-samples-data"
# config_path = f"{cloud_bucket}/instructions/sample_configuration.json"
# output_path = "custom_job/output/"

custom_job = aiplatform.CustomJob(
    display_name="Prompt Optimizer example",
    worker_pool_specs=[
        {
            "replica_count": 1,
            "container_spec": {
                "image_uri": "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai-restricted/builtin-algorithm/apd:preview_v1_0",
                "args": [f"--config={cloud_bucket}/{config_path}"],
            },
            "machine_spec": {
                "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
            },
        }
    ],
    staging_bucket=cloud_bucket,
    base_output_dir=f"{cloud_bucket}/{output_path}",
)

custom_job.submit()
print(f"Job resource name: {custom_job.resource_name}")
# Example response:
#    'projects/123412341234/locations/us-central1/customJobs/12341234123412341234'


After you run the Vertex AI prompt optimizer review the job's progress using one of the following options for these case I used Notebook:
If you want to view the results of the Vertex AI prompt optimizer through the notebook, do the following:

Open the Vertex AI prompt optimizer notebook.

In the Inspect the results section, do the following:
a. In the RESULT_PATH field, add the URI of the Cloud Storage bucket that you configured the Vertex AI prompt optimizer to write results to. For example, gs://bucket-name/output-path.
b. Click  Run cell.


After the whole process finished, you may get the Cloud Storage bucket that you configured the Vertex AI prompt optimizer to write results and feed it to the Gemini with grounding by doing this we have the optimized prompts stored in a bucket and run to grounding either google search or to your own data.

I don't think this works. I want to optimise the prompts based on the output from gemini with grounding rather than a normal gemini model. The former gives different responses and results
